# formated output with fprint in Makefile with pwd output

Tags: makefile, printf, gnu-make

In my Makefile I have this::

```
update:
    cd pkg_one && git fetch && git rebase
    @printf '  ==> [pkg_one] rebase Done, now in `pwd`\n'
```

I try to get the result of `pwd` in-lined with my printf commend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either remove the `pwd` from within the context of the single quotes with...

```
update:
    cd pkg_one && git fetch && git rebase
    @printf '  ==> [pkg_one] rebase Done, now in '`pwd`'\n'
```

or, use double quotes instead...

```
update:
    cd pkg_one && git fetch && git rebase
    @printf "  ==> [pkg_one] rebase Done, now in `pwd`\n"
```